# Which features are monkey patched by gunicorn gevent worker?

Tags: python, gevent, gunicorn

I am using gunicorn to run some flask and django applications, using the gevent worker, and have some questions...

First, I assume that because gunicorn fork and instantiate my processes, it will monkey patch the standard modules, and i do not have to call monkey.patch_all myself, it's already done for me, and each request is running as a greenlet, Is that correct?

Second, and this is the important part, which featues are really got monkey patched by gunicorn-gevent? 
when you use gevent, you can always choose which feature to patch(socket, patch, urllib)...
So, the question is , Which of these featured are really got monkey patched bu gunicorn-gevent? 
How can i change this list?

For example, the standard call to monkey.patch_all() does not patch urllib? 
How could i know if it was patched or not? and how to force gunicorn-gevent to patch it?

Thanks

Joe

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like the gevent worker calls monkey.patch_all() when it is initialized.

https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py#L45

You can still call your own initialization code when your app boots.

With flask I use gunicorn paster.

my_app.ini:

```
[app:main]
use = egg:mypackage#myapp
# app config goes here

[server:main]
use = egg:gunicorn#main
# you can put gunicorn config options here
```

setup.py in your package:

```
entry_points={
    'paste.app_factory': [
        'myapp = mypackage.module:app_factory'
    ]
```

example mypackage/module.py:

```
def app_factory(global_config, **config):
    # initialization code / gevent monkey patch goes here
    # also you can assemble your wsgi stack.
    # then return your flask app
    return app
```

Now you can run it:

```
gunicorn_paster my_app.ini
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip, it calls patch_all() which by default does not patch urllib, so how can i patch it at initialization? and is there a way to determined what is patched and what isn't? thanks

Comment: Not really but subsequent monkey patching is ok.

Comment: ok, some off-topic question: why gunicorn paster? what is its benefits? thanks

Comment: Well, taste it is, also a lot of server are using PasteDeploy lately.

Answer (score -1):

I have answered a simliar question and that may solve your problems.
Refer to this question: [Do I need call monkey.patch_all() in Django+Gunicorn+GEvent+Boto structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20425165/do-i-need-call-monkey-patch-all-in-djangogunicorngeventboto-structure/20436644#20436644)

First, the gunicorn use **SyncWorkers** as default and if you don't change the configuration, then the server won't use greenlets. And even though you monkey patch all, I think it doesn't have much help because gunicorn handles one request at a time as default.

Second, have a look at the source code of [GeventWorker](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py#L63) and it actually monkey patch all.

Comment: He says above in the first sentence that he is using the gevent worker type and then you just repeated exactly what the first answer said.