# Do I need call monkey.patch_all() in Django+Gunicorn+GEvent+Boto structure?

Tags: boto, gevent, gunicorn

My  website is using Django+Gunicorn+GEvent.
There is a function which I have to use Boto for DynamoDB.

Do I need call monkey.patch_all() to make Boto become greenlet?

Answer (score 3):

If you use the default **worker_class** configuration, then you don't have the features of gevent. Look the doc [here](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/design.html#sync-workers). I think you don't have the advantage of using gevent when you use the default configuration even though you monkey patch all.

So you should configure gunicorn to use the **GeventWorker** which does the `monkey.patch_all()` operation and in this situation, I think you don't have to monkey patch all. Here is the [source code](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py#L63) of `GeventWorker` and the doc about [worker_class](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/configure.html#worker-class)